# Aurelia Validation - revalidate rule when condition has changed

Tags: conditional-statements, updates, aurelia

Is there a way to revalidate conditional rule when condition has changed?

Lets say I have:
.ensure((entity: Entity) => entity.name).required().when((entity: Entity) => entity.isInitialized)

At the beginning error is not shown because although name is not provided entity is not initialized at this time. Problem is that when entity becomes initialized error is not displayed automatically.

Comment: Are you able to force the validation controller to run validation by manually invoking validate() method?  http://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/validation#validation-controller

Comment: @richardb Yes. Thats the solution I have ended up with. But in the context of the question I would consider it workaround.